# Calling a program(form) from another program(menu) in python

Tags: python

I have 2 programs, 1 is a menu called Calling.py and the other is a form called Called.py. I want the program to display the form upon the choice yet nothing displays. I need help, I just started learning python and this is keeping me at the same place for days.

```
    #Called.py

    from tkinter import * 
    import tkinter.messagebox


    class Student:


        def __init__(self,root):
            self.root=root
            self.root.title("Called Window")
            self.root.geometry("300x100+100+100")
            self.root.config(bg="red")

            MyName=StringVar()

            self.lbl1=Label(self.root, text="Name")
            self.lbl1.pack()
            self.Ent1=Entry(self.root, textvariable=MyName)
            self.Ent1.pack()



    if __name__=='__main__':
        root=Tk()
        application=Student(root)
        root.mainloop()

    # Calling.py

    from tkinter import *
    import Called

    root=Tk()
    root.geometry('700x500+100+100')
    root.title('Student Admin System')

    menu=Menu(root)
    root.config(menu=menu)
    def NewPupil():

    Called.Student

    def iExit():
        iExit=tkinter.messagebox.askyesno("Student DataBase Management System - Exit")
        if iExit > 0:
           root.destroy()
        return

     submenu=Menu(menu)
     menu.add_cascade(label='Student Administration', menu=submenu)
     submenu.add_command(label='New Student', command=NewPupil)
     submenu.add_command(label='Search/Print Student Record')
     submenu.add_command(label='Delete Student')
     submenu.add_command(label='Francis')

     root.mainloop()
```

Comment: `if __name__=='__main__':` in `Called.py` is always false because you don't start it as a script, you import it. Put the contents of that `if` in a function and start it when you want it.

Comment: OR here: `Called.Student` does nothing. You need `Called.Student(some_tk_object_here)`.

Comment: Thanks, the programs are here, what is the ('some_tk_object_here') since the two programs are clearly printed above. Which object do you mean?

Comment: In `Called.py` you do `root=Tk(); application=Student(root)` but only when the script starts by itself (`if __name__=='__main__':` line). `Calling.py` has its own `Tk` object called `root`, so it's possible you want to use it. I'm not a mind reader, I don't know what **you** wanted it to do.